# Netlify Page not found

Tags: http-status-code-404, netlify

I am trying to deploy my website but I keep getting a 404 error. I have a simple project organized in such way, :

```
html/index.html
css/style.css
js/script.js
```

I also tried to add a _redirect file in the html folder,but it keeps telling me "Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site."
How can I solve it ?